# Hiding MVC pages in production

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, production-environment, conditional-statements

I have a new MVC application which integrates into a larger pre-existing intranet site.

In production, authentication details will be passed from the existing intranet site. But in development I need a local forms login control to create the authentication.

This means I need a way to hide any of the local login pages when the solution is deployed to production server. I was trying to use `Debugger.IsAttached` to redirect away from any login page

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            RedirectToAction("NotFound");

        return View();
    }
}
```

It turns out this doesn't work. For some reason which is a mystery to me, the login page is still served when navigating to `/Account/LogOn`.

Can I fix this? Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd probably use custom action filters for this. That way you don't have to integrate debugging logic with controller logic.

Comment: Best comment/ handle combination. EVAR.

Comment: @Yuck that's a really nice idea, I would have given you the points if you'd written it as a proper answer.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet Passing comment, don't have time to write it up at the moment. Glad to have inspired you - good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of curiousity, are you aware of the "Authorize" attribute?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

You mention that your application is part of a larger application that I assume deals with the security (authentication), right ?

If so, in development, you could have a different/specific web.config for your needs.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">  
  <forms loginUrl="~/MyDevelopment/LogIn"/> //Just for dev
</authentication>
```

Also,

Instead of the Debugger.IsAttached, I suggest you use the compiler's directive

```
#if !DEBUG
    RedirectToAction("NotFound");
#endif
```

Comment: the `forms loginUrl` is not the issue, that won't prevent access to the pages directly through the URL. The DEBUG works where Debugger.IsAttached didn't though (for whatever reason, I don't really understand). I put this in a filter like Yuck suggested and it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a separate Web.config for both production and development, you can restrict access to this action in the Web.config of the production-environment:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="/Account/LogOn">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is the way to go.  You could also drive functionality off of the HTTP context in web applications (e.g., `Context.IsDebuggingEnabled`) but much better to use the web.config for this sort of thing.

Comment: The drawback being that this gives an access denied, rather than a not found.